# Use case for the task buildNeeded?

Tags: java, gradle

I don't understand why there is the task 'buildNeeded' which is provided by the java plugin.
Does not task 'build' solve the problem?
The gradle documentation says:

> buildNeeded: Performs a full build of the project and all projects it depends on.

and

> build: Performs a full build of the project.

Should / does not the task 'build' compile and build all the necessary things?
Why to distinguish between 'build' and 'buildNeeded'?

Comment: :D http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`buildNeeded` runs a full `build` for all projects that a project depends on. In particular it runs `test` for the depended-on projects, which can make sense if you want to play it safe. By comparison, `build` only runs a minimum set of tasks for the depended-on projects (e.g. `jar`), just enough to satisfy the dependency. `build` is used more often than `buildNeeded`.

Answer (score 1):

build does not call a full build on all child projects.

If you project has no dependent projects it doesn't make any difference.

The idea is that if you change API within a parent project you want to recompile all child projects with the new one.

Comment: Ok, i think i missed something. Is there a difference between sub project and child project? What about 'gradle clean build'?
Does this do the full build on the child/sub projects?

Comment: @Cengiz: gradle clean build will first do a clean (meaning it deletes your /build folder) and then do a build for the project only. It has the same effect as 'gradle clean' followed by 'gradle build'.